# Size of an array which is in static memory can be changed during run time in C++? How come?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have read this paragraph from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

> You could be wondering the difference between declaring a normal array
>   and assigning dynamic memory to a pointer, as we have just done. The
>   most important difference is that the size of an array has to be a
>   constant value, which limits its size to what we decide at the moment
>   of designing the program, before its execution, whereas the dynamic
>   memory allocation allows us to assign memory during the execution of
>   the program (runtime) using any variable or constant value as its
>   size.

But this code of mine works just fine:

```
int number;
cin>>number;
int myArray[number];

cout<<sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])<<endl;
cout<<sizeof(myArray)<<endl;
```

Does this mean the array is created in dynamic memory? Or is it created in static memory but the size of it still determined in runtime?

Comment: This code is using a gcc extension known as `variable length arrays`. It is not standard C++.

Comment: In addition to what @pmr says - AFAIK, it is added to the compiler for c99 compability,  (c99 supports VLA)

Comment: @amit: firstly it is C99, not C98, secondly FYI VLAs are optional since C11.

Comment: Yes, of course I mean C99, had a brain fart :| thanks.

Comment: Note that `cout<<sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])<<endl;` gives a good result as long as you don't pass the array to a function, then `sizeof(myArray)` will return the size of a pointer.

Comment: the array that you declared is not in the static memory, it is in an *automatic* memory (i.e. on the stack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment, but here with more detail.

In standard C++ the size of an array has to be known at compile time. In your example this is not the case. Your code compiles because you are (presumably) using gcc with the `variable length array` extension enabled.

Setting your warning level correctly will prevent this code from compiling.

Comment: Yes its true. It doesn't work on visual c++ 2013

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted doesn't work according to the C++ standard. Since variable length arrays are popular in C, the C++ compiler implementers may have decided that it is a good idea to make this feature available in C++, too. It certainly isn't a good idea to do it as it is done in C but some variations are being discussed for inclusion into C++.

It seems, gcc and clang accept the above code (after adding the necessary includes, a function, etc.). clang even does so without a warning.

Comment: +1 he he, no surprise that the dang compiler accepts it when g++ does. dang appears to be just be g++ clone (except that dang reportedly still fails to implement proper exception handling in Windows).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The fact that clang is so compatible with gcc makes it so popular, because there is close to zero overhead in porting involved.